# Dockerized mongodb using mongoimport imports json array as item

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongoimport

I am attempting to import a json array of items into my mongodb instance on Docker. When trying without Docker, mongoimport responds with `imported 7 documents` but in Docker it responds `imported 1 document`

Docker Command:

```
CMD mongoimport --host mongodb --db reach-engine --collection domains --type json --file seed.json --jsonArray
```

Docker MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc3abd7ccf9a826b2a7d34"), "items" : [ { "id" : 1, "_id" : "item1", "type" : "alert", "title" : "hello.world", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$9.00", "active" : true }, { "id" : 2, "_id" : "item2", "type" : "welcome.lol", "title" : "Item 2", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "lol", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : true }, { "id" : 3, "_id" : "item3", "type" : "message", "title" : "various.domain", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "lol", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$3.00", "active" : false }, { "id" : 4, "_id" : "item4", "type" : "message", "title" : "something.else", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }, { "id" : 5, "_id" : "item5", "type" : "update", "title" : "wow.lol", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }, { "id" : 6, "_id" : "item6", "type" : "update", "title" : "domainname.net", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "cars", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }, { "id" : 7, "_id" : "item7", "type" : "update", "title" : "something.lol", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false } ] }
```

Local MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc21cf1ebe0a21fa2fcdd4"), "title" : "hello.world", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$9.00", "active" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc21cf1ebe0a21fa2fcdd5"), "title" : "Item 2", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "lol", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc21cf1ebe0a21fa2fcdd6"), "title" : "wow.lol", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc21cf1ebe0a21fa2fcdd7"), "title" : "domainname.net", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "cars", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc21cf1ebe0a21fa2fcdd8"), "title" : "something.lol", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc21cf1ebe0a21fa2fcdd9"), "title" : "something.else", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc21cf1ebe0a21fa2fcdda"), "title" : "various.domain", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "lol", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$3.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2b7c1ebe0a21fa2fcddb"), "title" : "hello.world", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$9.00", "active" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2b7c1ebe0a21fa2fcddc"), "title" : "Item 2", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "lol", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2b7c1ebe0a21fa2fcddd"), "title" : "various.domain", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "lol", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$3.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2b7c1ebe0a21fa2fcdde"), "title" : "something.else", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2b7c1ebe0a21fa2fcddf"), "title" : "wow.lol", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2b7c1ebe0a21fa2fcde0"), "title" : "domainname.net", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "cars", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2b7c1ebe0a21fa2fcde1"), "title" : "something.lol", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2d691ebe0a21fa2fcde2"), "title" : "various.domain", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "lol", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$3.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2d691ebe0a21fa2fcde3"), "title" : "Item 2", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "lol", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2d691ebe0a21fa2fcde4"), "title" : "hello.world", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$9.00", "active" : true }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2d691ebe0a21fa2fcde5"), "title" : "wow.lol", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2d691ebe0a21fa2fcde6"), "title" : "domainname.net", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "cars", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58dc2d691ebe0a21fa2fcde7"), "title" : "something.lol", "email" : "something@something.com", "message" : "", "createdDate" : "date", "price" : "$12.00", "active" : false }
```

Docker CMD:

```
mongodb_1       | 2017-03-29T21:38:09.439+0000 I COMMAND  [conn1] command reach-engine.domains command: insert { insert: "domains", documents: [ { items: [ { id: 1, _id: "item1", type: "alert", title: "hello.world", email: "something@something.com", message: "", createdDate: "date", price: "$9.00", active: true }, { id: 2, _id: "item2", type: "welcome.lol", title: "Item 2", email: "something@something.com", message: "lol", createdDate: "date", price: "$12.00", active: true }, { id: 3, _id: "item3", type: "message", title: "various.domain", email: "something@something.com", message: "lol", createdDate: "date", price: "$3.00", active: false }, { id: 4, _id: "item4", type: "message", title: "something.else", message: "", createdDate: "date", price: "$12.00", active: false }, { id: 5, _id: "item5", type: "update", title: "wow.lol", email: "something@something.com", message: "", createdDate: "date", price: "$12.00", active: false }, { id: 6, _id: "item6", type: "update", title: "domainname.net", email: "something@something.com", message: "cars", createdDate: "date", price: "$12.00", active: false }, { id: 7, _id: "item7", type: "update", title: "something.lol", email: "something@something.com", message: "", createdDate: "date", price: "$12.00", active: false } ] } ], writeConcern: { getLastError: 1, w: 1 }, ordered: false } ninserted:1 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 reslen:40 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2, w: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 1, W: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { W: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 250ms
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Could you please point me to the Dockerfile / docker-compose structure you are using at the time of finding this issue?

Comment: Can you check the version of MongoDB you have installed locally and the version you have installed in your docker container? Also, is it possible to see a snippet of the JSON file?

Answer (score 4):

The docker mongo server behavior (possibly 3.x version) is correct i.e. inserting a single document with `items` as embedded array.

The local mongo behavior (possibly 2.x version) is because of JSON formatting issue.

I've followed below steps to reproduce the issue with the information provided in the post.

Consider **sample1.json**

`{items:[{item:1},{item:2},{item:3}]}`

Works exactly same in both 2.6 and 3.4 version.

**Collection**

`{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e44c281a573a105fe10d47"), "items" : [ { "item" : 1 }, { "item" : 2 }, { "item" : 3 } ] }`

Consider **sample2.json**  ( has `CRLF` )

`{"items":[{"item":1},
 {"item":2}, 
 {"item":3}]}`

It works same as above for 3.4 version but works differently in 2.6.

It fails while inserting the first element but continue inserting the next two element as separate document in 2.6 version.

**Command**

`mongoimport --db test --collection sample --type json --file sample2.json`

**Log**

`exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Bad characters in value: offset:21 of:{"items":[{"item":1},
2017-04-04T21:03:13.869-0500 imported 2 objects
encountered 1 error(s)`

**Collection**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e4506169a04993a1697f29"), "item" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e4506169a04993a1697f2a"), "item" : 3 }
```

**Fix:**

You have to update your json to below ( json formatting doesn't matter) to insert each element as a document and use `--jsonArray` flag. It works exactly the same in both 2.6 and 3.4.

Consider **sample.json**

`[{"item":1},
 {"item":2}, 
 {"item":3}]`

`mongoimport --db test --collection sample --type json --file sample.json --jsonArray`

**Log**

`2017-04-04T21:19:34.018-0500 imported 3 objects`

**Collection**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e454362a9c7ef0228df346"), "item" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e454362a9c7ef0228df347"), "item" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e454362a9c7ef0228df348"), "item" : 3 }
```

Comment: It seems this is doing the same thing even in Mongo 3.4.0 with --jsonArray, I am still testing with different JSON and getting same issue :(

Comment: Did you remove the items key ? Please update the post with latest json file and also did you verify mongo version  in local vs docker instance